# Can't login into Fedora 11?

Tags: fedora, login

I am using Fedora 11 with VMware Workstation for Unix.
I was performing `grep` command but as it doesn't display highlighted output so i found some commands and tried running them. Code is as below.

```
export PATH=/usr/bin
exec grep --color=auto --devices=skip "$@"
```

I added those commands in `.bashrc` file. After that I tried restarting the terminal but it doesn't open. So I restarted VMWare Workstation and Fedora and then logged in to default user student. But I can't login. It accepts password and again displays the screen of login.

So what is the problem?

Comment: Other than the fact that you exit the shell to run `grep`?

Comment: I know i copied that command without reading and without knowing meaning of it. My biggest mistake. as I got tired by trying lot of commands to highlight.:(

Comment: Now you get to start up in single mode to remove that line.